# Preferred customizable progressively enhanced dropdowns/menus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, yui

I was looking at what YUI had, http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/button/btn_example07.html

Can anyone recommend a library/plugin they used to progressively enhance native select element dropdowns at the request of a client? I know it's impossible to style a dropdown in IE, so it's either this or Flash which I don't want to get into.

I'll still leave the regular dropdown in the source for non-JS users and serve the dropdown replica built out of non-form control elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it wasn't all that difficult, pretty much the same logic as a dropdown menu except with a little extra for the toggling bit.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean a different library than YUI, I like [dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org)'s [dijit.form.FilteringSelect](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dijit/form/FilteringSelect).